# Undefined reference to _imp__CryptProtectData@28

Tags: c++, windows, qt, encryption

I am trying to build a simple application using the windows.h and wincrypt.h libraries so as to encrypt some strings.

When I call the function `CryptProtectData(&input, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, &output);` I get as error:

```
error: undefined reference to `_imp__CryptProtectData@28'
```

I have searched a lot the web and not much have come up. I also realized that Chromium browser uses similar code as mine so as to encrypt and decrypt its logins, and I am not doing something differently.

I am using the QtCreator IDE to compile my code.

Some of my code:

```
  std::string plaintext="Some plain text";
  DATA_BLOB input;
  input.pbData = const_cast<BYTE*>(
      reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(plaintext.data()));
  input.cbData = static_cast<DWORD>(plaintext.length());

  DATA_BLOB output;
  BOOL result = CryptProtectData(&input, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
                                 0, &output);
```

Edit: Forgot to mention that I have included the windows.h and wincrypt.h libraries, of course.

Comment: What is the command line you use to compile the whole lot? This error seems like you're missing a library.

Comment: @antonijn I leave the compilation to qt, which takes a loot at the .pro (project) file. There I should do the linking, but I am not sure how exactly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a linker error caused by the fact that you have not supplied the library file which is needed for the `CryptProtectData` function. You need to pass the `Crypt32` library to the linker.

This information is included in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa380261.aspx) for the function. Scroll down to the bottom of the topic to see the information.

As a general rule, in order to use an API function you need to look at the *Requirements* section in the function's documentation. That lists the following information:

- Minimum supported Windows version.
- The header file that you need to include.
- The library file that you need to pass to the linker.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am used at programming with linux and all linking was going through pkg, so I didn't have to do it manually. How do I link my project with crypt32.dll? I found it at C:\Windows\System32 and, as I said, I am using Qt. I tried adding to the .pro file: `INCLUDEPATH+=C:\Windows\System32` and `LIBS+=C:\Windows\System32\crypt32.dll` to no avail.

Comment: It's the .lib file that you need to pass to the linker rather than the DLL. The DLL is loaded at runtime. The .lib file is found in the Windows SDK that your compiler refers to. I expect that your link command also lists .lib files like user32, kernel32 and so on. You just need to add crypt32. Which compiler are you using? OK, I guess it is g++. I'm not really sure how your IDE allows you to set linker options.

Comment: @user9379 I am not sure about `Qt`, but windows provides `.lib`-files which contain the symbols. Can you add `.lib`-files in `Qt`?

Comment: Don't add system32 to INCLUDEPATH. Do add crypt32 to LIBS. Not 100% sure of the syntax. You should not need to include a path. For 100% sure nothing in system32 is relevant at the link stage. Just copy what is done for kernel32 etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. I understand that the problem is linking the specific library. How to do it is Qt specific and quite unrelated, thus, I mark this answer as correct.

Answer (score 3):

Have you linked to `Crypt32.dll` or rather `Crypt32.lib`? Add the .lib to your dependencies. When having such errors always see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).